# Adding ionic cli to existing ionic project

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I started using ionic without the cli and have built an app with ionic/cordova.

How can I add the ionic cli to this existing project?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- First Install Nodejs if you haven't
- You can verify whether you have nodejs by typing `node`
- Than install cordova and ionic globally by typing this command in cmd or terminal
  `npm install -g cordova ionic` If you get error than verify that you have npm installed.
- You have ionic installed
- Now open cmd/terminal navigate to your project and type `ionic`

Comment: $ npm install -g ionic

Answer (score 3):

Install nodejs if you haven't - https://nodejs.org

Now, once you installed node, you need to install cordova and ionic globally by using this command

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
```

***Note***: If you are using MAC you need to use `sudo` for admin rights

Once everything is loaded, you can start a project using:

`$ ionic start myApp bank` - starts from a blank project
or
`$ ionic start myApp tabs` - starts a tabs template

You can look for more templates at http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

**For existing Projects:**

cd to your existing project (make sure you already installed node, cordova and ionic)
Type in `$ ionic serve` that will run your app to the browser.
Need help on ionic type in `$ ionic --h`

Answer (score 1):

Install the Ionic CLI
The easiest way to get the Ionic CLI is through npm.

```
$ npm install -g ionic
```

Note: For a global install of -g ionic, OSX/Linux users may need to prefix the command with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

To have the listing of commands, write `ionic --help` in your command prompt

Answer (score 0):

First of all Install nodejs.

Now install cordova and ionic globally by this command in cmd or terminal
            `npm install -g cordova ionic` 
now open cmd/terminal and navigate to your project.
For execute the project in browser run command `ionic serve`
For launching app in android phone run command

```
ionic run android
```

For launching app in ios phone run command

```
ionic run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Install ionic in your project by usign command "sudo npm install -g ionic"
from your terminal/cmd,
and add cordova in project using "sudo npm install -g cordova".

Note that for installing ionic in your project you must have nodejs installed in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install node js from https://nodejs.org
2. Execute folowing commands in your terminal :

   - `npm install -g ionic@latest`
   - `npm install -g cordova`
   - `ionic serve`

Answer (score 0):

First install nodejs. Then install ionic and cordova cli:

```
npm install -g ionic (ionic cli) 

npm install -g cordova (cordova cli)
```

And for executing the project in the browser, run this command:

```
ionic serve
```

Answer (score 0):

install cordova and ionic globally by typing this command in cmd or terminal

**npm install -g cordova**

ionic If you get error than verify that you have npm installed